# Deploy Theme through Feature Sharepoint 2010

Tags: theme

Within my site definition i added module for the deployment of a theme.

The feature gets deployed, but when I activate it the theme is not available for selection?

I have included my elements.xml and not sure what is wrong? help?

Module Name="ThemeElement" Url="_catalogs/theme" RootWebOnly="true" Path="Themes">

```
File Url="SP.thmx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
```

/Module>

this is the SharepointProjectItem.spdata file for completeness

ProjectItem Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module" DefaultFile="Elements.xml" SupportedTrustLevels="All" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Web, Site" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2010/SharePointTools/SharePointProjectItemModel">
  Files>

```
ProjectItemFile Source="Elements.xml" Target="Theme\" Type="ElementManifest" />
ProjectItemFile Source="..\Theme\SP.thmx" Target="Theme\" Type="ElementFile" />
```

/Files>

/ProjectItem>

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it:

1. Create a Module SPI
2. Set Url for the  element to _catalogs/theme, List to 123 and RootWebOnly=true
3. Add the thmx file to the Module SPI and set the Type attribute on the  element to GhostableInLibrary
4. Add it to a Site Collection scoped feature
5. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Deploying custom themes is covered as part of the Advanced SharePoint Developer Training for SharePoint. Please check it out if that helps you:

http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/sharepoint-2010-user-interface-improvements-and-extensibility/10twboclq